# Can you make a Stack Panel type layout using CSS?

Tags: css, layout, stackpanel

I've had immense trouble googling this, I guess I don't quite know the name for the concept.  I have a section of the page where a series of text boxes will appear, the number might vary.  I'd like to have them fill a div in a top-to-bottom then left-to-right manner.  That is, the text boxes will stack (normal) until they reach the bottom then wrap around to the top again in a new column.

Like:

```
Textbox1    Textbox4    Textbox7
Textbox2    Textbox5    Textbox8
Textbox3    Textbox6
```

Is that possible in CSS, or will I need to actually code something to do this correctly?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the excellent responses.  CSS 3 isn't an option so I'll look into a server side or JS solution.  At least now I know what to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS columns, which is described on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css3multicolumn).

Note that this only works in modern browsers. Otherwise you need JavaScript or extra HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You want to Google "multi-column lists" using CSS.

Answer (score 2):

I personally call this newspaper columns, and there is [support for this in CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, CSS3 allows for this, though browser support is going to likely be mixed.

It wouldn't be too hard to do via JavaScript, though.